# How to make liquid template work as a layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, liquid

Here is a working application with Rails 3.1

https://github.com/neerajdotname/nimbleshop

All the views are working fine with .liquid extension except the layout.

I tried but I am unable to make the layout yield the content to the rendering page. 
This is what I tried in the layout

```
{{ content_for_layout }}
```

Comment: the layout is not liquid - it is ERB... to make it liquid you have to rewrite it... I can't seem to find any rewrite (partial or complete) from you... what have you tried ?... please elaborate!

Answer (score 0):

Also - for rails 3, to properly use liquid you need to update the liquid view so that it works with rails three and properly pulls the data for content_for_layout.

Look at the updated liquid view here --> https://gist.github.com/2914625

Comment: This update is posted in a gist here --> https://gist.github.com/2914625 sorry for the issues